Can the consistency of a complete recursively axiomatizable be decided?
It's known that the theorems of a complete, recursively axiomatizable theory $T$ must be decidable. Enderton proved this in his Corollary 25G by considering whether $T$ is consistent (Enderton's definition of completeness allows inconsistent theories to be complete): if it's consistent, we can search the proof for $p$ and $\neg p$ in parallel and eventually one (also exactly one) will appear; otherwise, the set of theorems in $T$ is the set of all sentences and is trivially decidable.
However, this proof doesn't tell me how to know whether $T$ itself is consistent or not. To make it clear, fix a numbering $\varphi$ of recursive functions. I want to know whether there exists an algorithm $\mathrm{CON}$ such that, if $\varphi_n$ is a decider of the axioms of some complete theory $T$, then $\mathrm{CON}(n)$ gives $0$ if $T$ is inconsistent and $1$ if $T$ is consistent.

Wikipedia's definition of completeness includes consistency as a hypothesis. AS far as I know, completeness is supposed to mean "for every proposition $p$, exactly one of $p$ or $\neg p$ is provable," and this implies consistency (since for an inconsistent theory both $p$ and $\neg p$ would be provable). In any case, in what situation would you know that a theory is either complete or inconsistent but not know which one?

@QiaochuYuan When consistency isn't assumed, the definition is "at least one of ..." - this is a bit uncommon (since there isn't much to say about inconsistent theories), but it does result in a meaningful question.

@QiaochuYuan Thank you for clarification. I'm using Enderton's definition, that a theory $T$ is complete if and only if for any sentence $p$, $T\vdash p$ or $T\vdash\neg p$, which allows inconsistent theories to be complete.

The answer to your question as stated is no.
Fix a sentence $\psi$ which axiomatizes a complete consistent theory. Let $p$ be an arbitrary program. Let $$T_p=\{\psi\}\cup\{\bigwedge_{i=1}^n\lnot \psi\mid p\text{ halts after $n$ steps}\}.$$
The theory $T_p$ has a recursive decider: to determine whether the axiom $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n\lnot \psi$ is in $T_p$, we just have to run the program $p$ for $n$ steps.
Note that $T_p$ is complete, since already $\psi$ is. And it is consistent if and only if $p$ does not halt. So by running CON on a recursive decider for $T_p$, we can determine if $p$ halts. Thus CON cannot exist.
The idea above of taking the conjunction of $n$ copies of $\lnot \psi$ is "Craig's trick". The point is to take the recursively enumerable theory consisting of $\psi$ together with $\lnot \psi$ if $p$ halts and turn it into a recursive theory.

The question is less trivial if we ask CON to apply not to recursive theories but to individual sentences. That is, is there a recursive function CON that takes in a sentence $\varphi$ and returns $0$ if $\varphi$ is complete and consistent, $1$ if $\varphi$ is inconsistent, and behaves arbitrarily otherwise?
Essentially the same question was asked by Thomas Klimpel here more than 10 years ago, but no conclusive answer was given.
One observation is that CON exists if and only if there is some recursively enumerable set $X$ such that $X$ contains all complete and consistent sentences, but $X$ contains no inconsistent sentences.
In one direction, if CON exists, the set of all inputs on which CON returns $0$ is recursively enumerable. Conversely, if some such set $X$ exists, we can define CON on $\varphi$ by simultaneously enumerating $X$ and the set of inconsistent sentences (by searching for proofs of contradictions). We halt if we find $\varphi$, outputting $0$ if it is in $X$ and $1$ if it is inconsistent.
I do not believe any such set $X$ exists, but I don't know how to prove it.

Re: Thomas' question, I think that the answer is (as expected) that no such $X$ exists. I'll write this up as a full answer later today when I have time, but here's the short version. First, show that the sets A,B of Turing machines which (on input 0, say) halt and output 0,1 respectively are recursively inseparable. Second, there's a trick (Hanf? Peretyat'kin?) where we can code a Turing machine by a single sentence $\sigma$ so that if the Turing machine halts (again, on fixed input 0 say) then $\sigma$ has exactly one model, namely a "presentation" of the full computation history. (cont'd)

Finally, given a machine $M$, we consider $\sigma'$ which is the conjunction of $\sigma$ and "It is not the case that we have a halting-and-outputting-zero state in our configuration." This $\sigma'$ is complete and consistent iff $M$ halts and doesn't output $0$, and is inconsistent iff $M$ halts and outputs $0$. Now apply the above inseparability. But even if this works there's still an ambiguity: the above argument assumes $CON$ is total, and doesn't work if "behaves arbitrarily otherwise" is allowed to include not giving an answer at all.

@NoahSchweber Nice. I did interpret both staroperator and Thomas as allowing "behaves arbitrarily otherwise" to include not giving an answer at all. They both phrased their question in the form "given a theory which we somehow know is either complete and consistent or inconsistent..." which suggests we don't care about getting an answer in any other case.

Yeah, that's one of the things I hope to address later today or tomorrow! I think the same sort of approach can be made to work with some further bells and whistles, but I'm not certain.
